# Issue with impacket & python

Tags: python, python-2.7, impacket

Hi there boys and girls,

I am trying to run a script written in python and the console is telling me this:

```
Install the following library to make this script work
Impacket : https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket.git
PyCrypto : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto
```

The problem is that I have already installed those python packages in python3 so when I make a request via pip for those packages I receive this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: impacket in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.9.17)
Requirement already satisfied: ldap3>=2.5.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from       impacket) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from impacket)    (1.15.0)
```

Hid the rest of the lines but the idea is that. I understand that the package is already installed in my system but I cannot use those with python2.7.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error is because you have not installed impacket for python2.7.

- Before installing impacket we need to install pip2 in python2.7, Download get-pip.py form [Link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/)
- if pip2 is already installed you can verify this by
  **pip --verison**, output of that command should be
  **pip 20.3.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)**
- If pip2 is not installed then install pip2 in python2 package using **sudo python2 get-pip.py**
- Next, install impacket for python2 using **pip install .** (this must be with in the impacket directory [link](https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket.git))
- then try to run your script

Comment: python2 get-pip.py                                                              1 ⨯
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpLf3XF2/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax